# android open a fragment which is in navigation drawer from an activity which is not navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have 4 buttons on the main activity screen.

I also have a menu with 4 items and I want to show it using a navigation drawer. I described these 4 items as fragments and the fragment container were included in the navigation drawer activity.

What I want to do is reach these 4 fragments from the main activity, but in my main activity I can't reach the fragment container. What should I do? is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You should show some relevant code. Although some experts can answer you without any code, text-only questions are usually not attracting and more difficult to understand. Best regards

Comment: Is it important that main activity screen has 4 buttons? If so, please specify why. I've edited the text a bit; please add the code for the main screen after the first paragraph and the code for menu/fragments after the second paragraph. Also, I'd recommend to describe the expected result in non-technical terms: you may have limited yourselft in solving a real problem by some approach while another approach can help.